# Flutter FutureBuilder calling function continuously

Tags: flutter, dart

I have simple function which is calling data from firestore and filtering data. But issue is my futurebuilder keeps on loader situation (Data is called successfully i can see in console but now showing in future) I think its because my fucntion is calling in loop or something i have try to print something in my function which indicates me that my function is not stopping and thats why i think my futureBuilder keeps on loading.

My code

```
  Future<List> getCustomerList() async {
    print('calling');
    String uUid1 = await storage.read(key: "uUid");
    String uName1 = await storage.read(key: "uName");
    String uNumber1 = await storage.read(key: "uNumber");

    setState(() {
      uUid = uUid1;
      uName = uName1;
      uNumber = uNumber1;
    });

    CollectionReference _collectionRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Customers');
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.get();

    // Get data from docs and convert map to List
    List allData = querySnapshot.docs
        .where((element) => element['sellerUID'] == uUid)
        .map((doc) => doc.data())
        .toList();
    double gGive = 0;
    double gTake = 0;
    double gCal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
      // print(allData[i]);

      // print('give ${double.parse(allData[i]['give'].toString()) }');
      // print('take ${double.parse(allData[i]['take'].toString()) }');
      double.parse(allData[i]['give'].toString()) -
                  double.parse(allData[i]['take'].toString()) >
              0
          ? gGive += double.parse(allData[i]['give'].toString()) -
              double.parse(allData[i]['take'].toString())
          : gTake += double.parse(allData[i]['give'].toString()) -
              double.parse(allData[i]['take'].toString());
    }

    // print(gGive);
    // print(gTake);

    setState(() {
      Gtake = gGive.toString().replaceAll("-", "");
      Ggive = gTake.toString().replaceAll("-", "");
    });

    if (greenBox) {
      var check = allData.where((i) => i['take'] > i['give']).toList();

      return check;
    } else if (redBox) {
      var check = allData.where((i) => i['give'] > 1).toList();
      return check;
    } else {
      return allData;
    }
  }
```

And my futureBuilder look like this

```
 Expanded(
  child: Container(
    height: Height * 0.5,
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getCustomerList(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            list = snapshot.data;
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  
                  Container(
                    height: Height * 0.5,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: list.length,
                      itemBuilder:
                          (BuildContext context,
                              int index) {
                        var showThis = list[index]
                                ['give'] -
                            list[index]['take'];

                        return list[index]
                                    ['customerName']
                                .toString()
                                .contains(searchString)
                            ? GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            CustomerData(
                                                data: list[
                                                    index])),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets
                                              .only(
                                          left: 13,
                                          right: 13),
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration:
                                        BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border(
                                          top: BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors
                                                  .grey,
                                              width:
                                                  .5)),
                                    ),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          const EdgeInsets
                                                  .all(
                                              13.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                .spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              CircleAvatar(
                                                child:
                                                    Text(
                                                  list[index]['customerName'][0]
                                                      .toString(),
                                                  style:
                                                      TextStyle(fontFamily: 'PoppinsBold'),
                                                ),
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    Color(0xffF7F9F9),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width:
                                                    20,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                list[index]['customerName']
                                                    .toString(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily:
                                                        'PoppinsMedium'),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            'RS ${showThis.toString().replaceAll("-", "")}',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily:
                                                    'PoppinsMedium',
                                                color: list[index]['give'] - list[index]['take'] <
                                                        0
                                                    ? Colors.green
                                                    : Colors.red),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : Container();
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else
            return Center(
              heightFactor: 1,
              widthFactor: 1,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 70,
                width: 70,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  strokeWidth: 2.5,
                ),
              ),
            );
        }),
  ),
),
```

I am damn sure its because futurebuilder keeps calling function which is returning data but because of keeps calling functions my Futurebuilder keeps showing loading.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call setState inside the future that you are giving to the FutureBuilder.

The state actualization will cause the FutureBuilder to re-build. Meaning triggering the future again, and ... infinite loop !

Comment: Thanks but after this issue is then its not changing the list data. Mean its just calling function one time issue is my data is updating and i need to update the Future list and for this i need to call the function not continuesly but in few seconds

Comment: Then you should probably not use a FutureBuilder ! Just store the result of the future inside a variable inside your state. And refresh the variable with setState and Stream.periodic. If this sounds 'strange' to you I can give you a little example.